# How to show a tensor is symmetric

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

What is the best method for showing that a tensor is a symmetric tensor?

For instance, I would like to show that the second fundamental form
$$II_{ab}=\nabla^T_a \hat{n}_b \big\vert_\Sigma$$
where $\Sigma$ is a restriction to a hypersurface is a symmetric tensor.

I thought about using the theorem that states "the product of a symmetric and antisymmetric tensor is zero" might be a way to do this, but am not sure if there's an easier method for showing such a tensor is symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at how the tensor acts on the two vectors $a$ and $b$. And then compare this to the result when you interchanged $a$ and $b$. If the result is the same for general $a, b$ then you have your proof.

Comment: How it acts on two vectors $v$ and $w$ simultaneously? Like $T_{ab} (v_a \frac{\partial}{\partial x^a})(v_b \frac{\partial}{\partial x^b})$?

Comment: In your case you should just interchange the $a$ and $b$.

Comment: So let the second fundamental form act on two vectors, then interchange the indices and let it act on the same two vectors?

Comment: I might have expressed myself badly. The indices arise by letting the tensor act on the basis vectors. So what symmetry in fact means is that $T_{ij}= T_{ji}$. So, in your case, if you let the second fundamental form act on two basis vectors $e_i$ and $e_j$, or you interchange them. Then you should obtain the same result.